# Solving the General Equilibrium with $4$ equations and $4$ unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, economics, maple

I have to solve four equations to solve the equlilibrium prices for the two countries:

1. $\frac{2p_1}{w_1} + \frac{p_1}{w_2}= \frac{48w_1^2 + 4p_1^2+p_2^2}{8p_1w_1}+ \frac{48w_2^2+p_1^2+4p_2^2}{8p_1w_2}$
2. $\frac{p_2}{2w_1} + \frac{2p_2}{w_2}= \frac{48w_1^2 + 4p_1^2+p_2^2}{8p_2w_1}+ \frac{48w_2^2+p_1^2+4p_2^2}{8p_2w_2}$
3. $48w_1^2=4p_1^2+p_2^2$
4. $48w_2^2=4p_2^2+p_1^2$

I have set $w_2=1$ and that leaves me with four equations and three unknowns. However, it is still very hard to solve for the $p_1$,$p_2$, and $w_1$ (we already know that $w_2=1$). On paper, I have a plethora of substitutions and sub-equations going on, but I don't think I am going anywhere with it, and so need some professional advice.

**Edit:** Is there a way for me to use **Maple** to solve this system of equations?

Comment: First of all, get rid of the fractions. Multiply with the main denominator.

Comment: @Peter I don't quite understand why there should not be any solution. If there is no solution then we cannot solve for the equilibrium prices. But I think the prof realised that the computation here is rather cumbersome and so instructed us to take $w_1=w_2$. But I do have an objection to that as in economics if the labour is immobile in two markets then we cannot assume that wages are equal in the two markets.

Comment: The claim, that there is no solution, was not from me! I only answered to a comment.

Comment: Maple says (tacitly) that there are no solutions. I tried both numeric and symbolic solvers.

Comment: @CarlLove Thought so. Thanks for trying and letting me know.